# How to obtain the binary literal from a integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary, literals

I would like to get the binary literal corresponding from a given integer, in this way:

> > 4.to_literal
> >     => 0b100

Is there such `to_literal` method?

Comment: Why do you want a literal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `to_s` with its optional base parameter to get a string.

```
4.to_s(2) #=> "100"
```

You can't get a literal as output.

Comment: and, when you need it, "100".to_i(2) #=> 4.

Comment: I was kind of confused. I don't actually need a literal, but a binary mask that has the 4th bit on and the rest off, but that's another question. I'm marking your answer since you're the first and actuallty addressed my question with ``can't get a literal as output.``

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) or [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) (`%#b` as format specifier):

```
'%#b' % 4
# => "0b100"
sprintf('%#b', 4)
# => "0b100"
```

Comment: Hey! Mark was faster and he actually answered my (confused) question about getting literals as output. You're approach is also quite interesting, you actually provide the literal in string format ... but it was my question that was wrong. But thanks anyway for your answer!